# NET versions supported by Azure (IaaS, PaaS)

Tags: .net, azure

Surprisingly difficult to answer - which versions of the .NET framework are supported by Azure (in both IaaS and PaaS flavours)?
Links would be great.

Comment: I would also add SaaS into the mix

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn479282.aspx?

Comment: What particular Azure offering do you want to know about?

Comment: Conveniently, this is a pretty easy thing to test. Try deploying a basic hello world project with desired framework versions to PaaS roles. Bonus points for making Hello World dump the version of .net. In IaaS, you have a vm. You can install any version of .net you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PaaS Roles (Web, Worker) it will depend on which GuestOS version you select. The details of supported Framework versions are [available on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj573576.aspx).

IaaS Virtual Machines run Server 2008 and above so any Framework version that suports those platforms can be run there.  Full server support matrix for [.Net Framework is also on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).